# If statement in xsl

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to only include the following line of code if parent_item_id doesn't contain a value.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="parent_item_id"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />
```

For context - this is a sales export from Magento 2.

I've tried wrapping it with an if statement but I don't know what I'm doing!

```
<xsl:if parent_item_id= ''">
... 
</xsl:if>
```

This is the full code if it helps.

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:text>"Merchant Identifier","Order Ref","Date","Product Search Code","Parent","Description","Customer Name","Customer Email"&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text> <!-- This is the header line of the CSV file. It gets output once only, the &#xD;&#xA; characters represent a line break that gets output after the header line. -->

<xsl:for-each select="objects/object"> <!-- for-each means that the template will loop through the objects/object nodes in the XML processed. So for every object (order, invoice, ...) the code below will be applied. -->
<xsl:for-each select="items/item"> <!-- Loop through items ordered -->
<!-- This means, loop through all items of an object and output the following: -->
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" />fff<xsl:value-of select="$sepend" /> 
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="../../increment_id"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" /> <!-- The $sepstart variable outputs " to start a new field in the CSV file. Then using xsl:value-of select="../../increment_id" the "increment_id" field is pulled from the object level. ../../ means to get data from the "parent" level (we are looping through items and not through objects (orders). The $sepend variable then outputs ", to denote the end of the field in the CSV file. -->
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="../../created_at"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" /><!-- Order date -->
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="product_attributes/sku"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" /> <!-- Get the "sku" field  -->
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="parent_item_id"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" /> <!-- Get the "sku" field  -->

<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" /> <!-- Get the "sku" field on item level -->
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="../../shipping/prefix"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../../shipping/firstname"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../../shipping/lastname"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" /><!-- Name (prefix, forename, surname) -->
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="../../customer_email"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" /><!-- customer email -->
<xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each> <!-- End item foreach -->



</xsl:for-each> <!-- End object foreach -->

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</file>
</files>
```

Comment: The expression you want is `<xsl:if test="parent_item_id= ''">` although is this really what you want to do as it would mean for this particular row the remaining fields wouldn't align with the field headers? Also, you wouldn't then need to do `<xsl:value-of select="parent_item_id"/>` because it would be empty, and output nothing anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including the input and the expected output.

Comment: Thank you. I will try Tim's suggestion first. Really appreciate the replies.

Comment: Oh wow. With all your help I managed to do exactly what I wanted. I'm sure it's not the cleanest way of doing it but I added an IF for when a parent_id exists, and another IF statement for when it is empty. However I had to use not(string(.)) to identify it was empty.  Thanks.